# Floated content in header, Semantic UI

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'd like to include floated content in a header using [Semantic Ui](http://semantic-ui.com/).

Here is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
<h1 class="ui dividing header">
  Header text
  <div class="ui right floated labels">
    <div class="ui green empty circular label"></div>
    <div class="ui red empty circular label"></div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/25ea6w9p/2/

This, of course, doesn't work though. Is there a way to add floated content to the header?

Thanks!

Edit: Works with `span` - thanks!

Comment: can you add a fiddle with this code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/25ea6w9p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting divs inside a H1 tag is not valid HTML. However you can change the divs to spans and this will work.